# ssh into aws server and edit hosts file

Tags: python, python-2.7, amazon-web-services, ssh, boto

My code:

For some reason this seems to infinite loop and repeatedly print 'here2' and the output of 'ls -lah'. Is there something bleedingly obvious I'm doing wrong?

```
def update_hosts_file(public_dns,hosts_file_info):
    for dns in public_dns:
        print 'here2'
        ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
        ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy()) # wont require saying 'yes' to new fingerprint
        key_path = os.path.join(os.path.expanduser(KEY_DIR), KEY_NAME)+'.pem'
        ssh.connect(dns,username='ubuntu',key_filename=key_path)
        ssh.exec_command('touch testing')
        a,b,c=ssh.exec_command("ls -lah")
        print b.readlines()
        a,b,c=ssh.exec_command("file = open('/home/ubuntu/hosts', 'w')")
        #print b.readlines()
        ssh.exec_command("file.write('127.0.0.1 localhost\n')")
        for tag,ip in hosts_file_info.iteritems():
            ssh.exec_command("file.write('%s %s\n' % (ip,tag))")
        ssh.exec_command("file.close()")
        ssh.close()

public_dns = 'ec2-xx-xxx-xxx-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com'
print public_dns
hosts_file_info = {}
#hosts_file_info['1']='test'
#hosts_file_info['2']='test2'
#hosts_file_info['3']='test3'
#print hosts_file_info
update_hosts_file(public_dns,hosts_file_info)
```

Comment: It looks like you're trying to execute Python statements as if they were bash commands, like `file = open('/home/ubuntu/hosts', 'w')`. I'm not sure whether that will give you a bash syntax error, or an error from `file` like `cannot open '=' (No such file)`, but I am sure it won't do anything useful.

Comment: BTW, check out Fabric http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.8/. It makes a lot of this style of automation easy and convenient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first problem is that `public_dns` is a string, so `for dns in public_dns:` will iterate over the characters of that string. You'll try the code with `'e'`, then with `'c'`, then with `'2'`, and so on. That's not an infinite loop, but it's a loop of length 42, and I could easily see you getting bored and canceling it before that finishes.

If you only want a single server, you still need a list of strings, it's just that the list will only have one string, like this:

```
public_dns = ['ec2-xx-xxx-xxx-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com']
```

---

Your next problem is that your ssh code doesn't make any sense. You're trying to execute Python statements, like `file = open('/home/ubuntu/hosts', 'w')`, as if they were bash commands. In bash, that command is a syntax error, because you can't use parentheses that way in shell scripts. And if you fixed that, it would just be a call to the `file` command, which would complain about not being able to find a file named `=`. You could upload a Python script to the remove server and then run it, embed one via a `<<HERE`, or try to script the interactive Python interpreter, but you can't just run Python code in the bash interpreter.

On top of that, `exec_command` starts a command, and immediately returns you the stdin/stdout/stderr channels. It doesn't wait until the command is finished. So, you can't sequence up multiple commands by just doing `a,b,c = ssh.exec_command(…)` one after another.

---

So, how could you fix this? It really makes more sense to start over again than to try to figure out what each part of this was intended to do and how to make it work.

As far as I can tell, on each machine, you're trying to create a new file, whose contents are based only on data you have locally, and the same on all machine. So, why even try to run code on each remote machine that creates that file? Just create it locally, once, and upload it to each remote machine—e.g., with Paramiko's [`sftp`](http://www.lag.net/paramiko/docs/paramiko.SFTPClient-class.html). Something like this (obviously untested, because I don't have your data, server credentials, etc.):

```
hosts = ['127.0.0.1 localhost\n']
for ip, tag in hosts_file_info.iteritems():
    hosts.append('%s %s\n' % (ip,tag))
for dns in public_dns:
    ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
    # etc. up to connect
    sftp = paramiko.SFTPClient.from_transport(ssh.get_transport())
    f = sftp.open('/home/ubuntu/hosts', 'w')
    f.writelines(hosts)
    f.close()
```

Comment: Thanks mate, didn't know I could use sftp like that

Answer (score 2):

You're looping through every letter in the public_dns variable.  You probably want something like this:

```
public_dns = ['ec2-xx-xxx-xxx-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com']
```